# @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) What does this code in android indicates

Tags: android

I'm developing an android app in eclipse. My ide shows a tip to generate this line.I added it to my code:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
```

What does this code indicate? Will the app be restricted with the GINGERBREAD version alone?

Answer (score 5):

Indicates that Lint should treat this type as targeting a given API level, no matter what the project target is(It just suppress the Lint error)

via Android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/annotation/TargetApi.html)

e.g. if Lint detects that you are using something newer than your android:minSdkVersion, but up to API Level GingerBread, Lint will not complain.

Comment: Can u brief me wat is Lint or send me some link about it.

Comment: Sure, [here](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint) and [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/improving-w-lint.html). In short, it's a tool that checks code and shows if something may be wrong

Comment: regarding the @TargetAPI, I got request to add "@TargetAPI" when I used editor.apply() (which is api9+ only) while coding a target_sdk8 app.  What happens when api 8 devices run into the api9+ line of code?  Will it get runtime error? Is it best or possible to build a release version for more than one api level (one for api 8 and another for api9+) or is it better to dynamically check by somehow coding and detecting the current device api and then load appropriate line of code. ex. if device is using api 8 or lower use editor.commit() else use editor.apply()?

Comment: @cjayem13 you have to manually check if code is not executed on older platforms using Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ANDROID_VERSION_HERE. "@TargetApi" only works for lint.

Comment: ok cool. I found instructions at http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html on how to check for build version at runtime. Thanks for the help.